# Working with Modern Standard Arabic locale in PHP

Tags: php, localization

I am working with locales and I have a problem dealing with the Modern Standard Arabic language in PHP.

When I do a `print_r(ResourceBundle::getLocales(''))` I get the following list http://pastebin.com/raw/qhBawQ5C

I can see the locale `ar` in the list so I am assuming its available on my machine.

Now when I run `echo Locale::getRegion('ar');` I get an empty value. But when I run `echo Locale::getRegion('ar_BH');` I get `BH`.

Why is this and how can I make the ar locale work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ar` does not have a region... It generally indicates "Arabic" as a region-independent language. `ar_BH` is specific to Bahrain, which obviously *is* a region.

Comment: Try to get its value by array key not by array value, OR Convert your array value in caps OFF/ON mode --> like : ar/AR

Answer (score 1):

Both is written on php.net. Just read it carefully.

- Function [`getLocales`](http://php.net/manual/en/resourcebundle.locales.php) returns all locales supported by class `ResourceBundle` (available in ICU library, via intl extension), if argument is missing.
- Function [`getRegion`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getregion.php) returns *region subtag* for locale, or `NULL` if not present. For this you get BH, if you write `ar_BH` as argument for this function.

On php.net is written example with different example, but its the same.

```
Locale::getRegion('de-CH-1901');
output: CH

Locale::getRegion('ar_BH');
output: BH
```

And that `getRegion()` returns nothing, if `ar` was set, then it is because it does not see any *region subtag* in argument - because all localisation codes are assembled from two (or may be three, as the first example says) parts.

And if those parts have strictly given order, it cannot show any region if only `ar` was set. But to gfive you any more exact answer, I should know how it (ICU library) was written.

Buit I did minor test for you.

Localisation code for my native language is `cs_CZ`.

```
Locale::getRegion(`cs_CZ`);
output: CZ

Locale::getRegion(`cs`);
output: /* nothing */

Locale::getRegion(`CZ_cs`);
output: cs
```

and now, code for you

```
Locale::getRegion(`BH_ar`);
output: ar
```

Comment: ok you didnt get my question.

It works when i run Locale::getRegion('ar_BH'); //Outputs BH
It doesnt work when I run Locale::getRegion('ar'); //No output

Why?

Comment: I added some information for you. I hope that it will be sufficient.